# asynchronous socket connection in php

Tags: php, sockets, asynchronous, while-loop

i'm trying write asynchronous socket listener code in php. but listener response answer only for first request and for other requests it only can receive packets without response (i'm checking with sniffer) also i'm counting how many time loop was active and loop is active only for first request ...... i'll show my Code :

```
addr = '192.168.0.117';
$port = 7878;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $addr, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
socket_listen($sock);

$null = NULL;
$clients = Array();
$cc = 0; // loop counter

while(true){

    echo $cc."<br>";
    $cc = $cc +1;

    $read[0] = $sock;

    $ready = socket_select($read,$null,$null,$null);    
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    $input = socket_read($client, 312); 


    echo $input;

    if($input == "exit"){
        socket_close($client);
        socket_close($sock);
        return false;
    }

    $output = 0x11;
    socket_write($client,$output);
    $input = "";
}
```

Comment: FYI: This isn't asynchronous

Comment: thanks colin for information, but can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are closing the listening socket right after the first client sends `exit` command. You should close only `client` socket when the client sends `exit` command. And you `return false` from the `while` loop. This means obviously it will process only one client.

```
if($input == "exit"){
   socket_close($client);
   socket_close($sock);  // Think about this Line.
   return false; // Think about this Line.
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer shazin, this command exit is for all client that was right... here is not problem... problem is into loop when comes first request for example "3401000031313639313030303938383334380051" server receives it and prints into screen... but after 1 packet only sniffer can see packet is receivet in same local port but my server can't display into screen and loop counter is again 0. when i send request "exit" from another server it can recive it and loop number is 1. it looping only for new connection but i need loop every new async packet... P.S sorry for bad english

Comment: @user1360571 You need to pick a new language if you want true asynchronous communication. As it stands, this is synchronous and blocking. Your `socket_read` will hang until it receives 312 bytes of data, or the connection is closed (whichever comes first). Look up `stream_set_blocking` in the PHP manual, but understand that it won't solve all of your problems. PHP is not intended to be asynchronous like this. Consider using something like node.js for this project if these are your requirements.